# Evaluating the closed integral of an elliptical path

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been working on a problem that states:

Evaluate $\int F*dr $ where

$F(x,y,z) = x\,i+xy\,j+x^2yz\,k $ and C is the elliptical path given by

$$ x^2+4y^2-8y+3=0 $$ in the xy-plane, traversed once counter-clockwise.

I'm having a bit of difficulty, however I'm thinking that we need to start by defining our elliptical in terms of t, and then getting bounds for t to use as our integration bounds? I'm really confused on how to go about this, though and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think Green's Theorem is in order.

Comment: @Nameless how would I go about applying it in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the ellipse's equation will be: $$x^2+4(y^2-2y+1)-1=0\Rightarrow x^2+4(y-1)^2=1\Rightarrow \vec r=(\sin t,\frac{\cos t}{2}+1)\Rightarrow \vec {dr}=(cost,-\frac{sin t}{2})$$
if we assume a clockwise orientation
then $\vec F=(\sin t,\sin t(\frac{cos t}{2}+1),1)$
then $\vec F.\vec{dr}=\sin t\cos t-\frac{\sin^2 t}{2}(\frac{cos t}{2}+1)$
then $\int_0^{2\pi} \vec F.\vec{dr}=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin t\cos t-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2 t\cos t-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2 t$
then $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin t\cos t dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin 2tdt=\frac{-1}{4}(\cos 2t)_0^{2\pi}=0$
then $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos t\sin^2tdt=\frac{1}{3}(\sin^3t)_0^{2\pi}=0 $
then $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2t=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos 2t)dt=\pi-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos 2tdt=\pi-\frac{1}{4}(\sin 2t)_0^{2\pi}=\pi$
thus $$Original integral=0-\frac{1}{4}(0)-\frac{1}{2}(\pi)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: It should be note that if you let $x = \sin t$ and $y = (1/2)\cos t + 1$, the orientation is **clockwise**.

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me, it may be better to do this directly. I assume you mainly have problems with the parametrization.

After [completing the square](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2B4y%5E2-8y%2B3%3D0+complete+the+square), you should get $$x^2 + \frac{(y - 1)^2}{1/4} = 1$$

The most natural parametrization is $x = \cos t$ and $y = 1 + (1/2)\sin t$. The bounds are $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

I assume you can handle the rest as it is just plug and chug. But let me know if a problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

For line integral appears in homework or exercise (instead of real world),
it is very common one don't need to parametrize anything to compute the integral.

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the ellipse 
$$x^2 + 4y^2 - 8y + 3 = 0 \iff x^2 + 4(y-1)^2 = 1.\tag{*1}$$
The integral we want to evaluate is
$$\mathcal{I} \stackrel{def}{=} \int_\mathcal{E} xdx + xydy + x^2yz dz$$

1. Notice $xdx = \frac12 dx^2$ is a total differential, its line integral over any closed loop, say $\mathcal{E}$, vanishes.
2. $\mathcal{E}$ lies in the plane $z = 0$, so the third term $x^2yz dz$ contribute nothing.
3. We are left with the term $xy dy$, we can transform it as
   $$xy dy = \frac12 x dy^2 = -\frac18 x d(x^2 - 8y + 3) = -\frac14 x^2 dx + x dy $$
   The term $-\frac14 x^2 dx$ is again a total differential and its line integral over $\mathcal{E}$ vanishes. This leads to
   $$\mathcal{I} = \int_\mathcal{E} x dy$$
   Since the orientation of $\mathcal{E}$ is counter-clockwise, the integral at
   RHS is the area enclosed by $\mathcal{E}$.

   From $(*1)$, we see $\mathcal{E}$ is an ellipse with semi-major axis $1$ along the $x$-direction and semi-minor axis $\frac12$ along the $y$-direction. 
   This means the area enclosed by $\mathcal{E}$ is $\pi\cdot 1 \cdot \frac12 = \frac{\pi}{2}$. As a result, the line integral we want to compute also equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.